# Invalid Response when attaching to tangle

Tags: wallet, exchanges

I'm trying to send IOTAs from Binance to my IOTA wallet 2.5.6.

I generated an address and copied it into the withdrawal section of Binance. Then I submitted and confirmed it in Binance.

When the Binance transaction history is said "processing" I hit the "attach to tangle" in my IOTA wallet. After some time I got a red "Invalid response" in the "attach to tangle" button.

The history in Binance still says processing. Have I done something wrong? Or do I have to wait until Binance has finished processing?

Answer (score 2):

When you clicked on `ATTACH TO TANGLE`, you just created a new address from your seed and attached a 0-value-transaction to the tangle. You can receive Iotas to addresses which aren't *attached to the tangle*.

The "Invalid response" error is displayed whenever the full node your light wallet is connected to sends an unexpected response. This can happen for several reasons and it's probably unrelated to Binance or any pending transactions.

If you pasted the correct address into the withdrawal section of Binance, you probably just have to wait. You can check all of your addresses in the `HISTORY` section in the light wallet.

Comment: Only to underline what @Zauz said: once an address is generated inside the wallet and so we know it, we can use it and receive IOTA on it regardless of whether we attached to the tangle or not.

Answer (score 0):

I hadn´t entered to my wallet for the las 18 months. Recently when I installed the wallet again (the new one - Trinity), I had my balance in 0 and also my address didn´t attach to Tangle

The solution to this problem was the following.

1. I had to install the previous stable wallet -  Iota light wallet 2.5.7
2. Entered to my seed and tried to attach to Tangle. Had the invalid Response
3. Turned off the firewall of windows.
4. Tried other host nodes. After failing with many, I achieved the following working host

https://nodes.thetangle.org:443

5. Tried to attach to Tangle, and It succeeded. Generated new address and attached to Tangle again. Just repeated this operation again, after seeing my balance again

I hope the developers will soon automatize all this operations , so you won´t have to suffer again in these cases.